# How to write to the appSettings from an F# console application?

Tags: f#, console-application, configurationmanager

Although it seems lie a simple issue, I am unable to write to a configuration file from an F# console application. My last attempt looks like

```
let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
// config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition <-ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser
match self.FileName with
| Some name -> config.AppSettings.Settings.["FileName"].Value <- name
| None -> ()
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

I got all sorts of errors. The one corresponding to this code is

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.SetPropertyValue(ConfigurationProperty prop, Object value, Boolean ignoreLocks) ...

There is no good documentation in F# and I find it hard to follow C#/VB documentation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can it be that `KeyValueConfigurationElement` in question is simply absent? If not, you have to `Settings.Add(key, value)` it first.

Comment: When using `Settings.Add` the fault is `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for appSettings. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.`

Comment: Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx) sample on MSDN. If you have **just** created a section, you may need to reload it so that its values became available for reading. If that does not help, please consider adding more details to your question so it was easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for null and either update or add accordingly.

Something like this:

```
let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
let settings = config.AppSettings.Settings
let set (s:KeyValueConfigurationCollection) key value = 
   match s.[key] with 
   | null -> s.Add(key,value)
   | x    -> x.Value <- value
match self.FileName with
| Some name -> set settings "Filename" name
| _         -> ()
```